# Inverse Fourier transform in 3D

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Dear Friends can you help me for solution of inverse fourier transform in 3D. Integral is:

$\int {\frac{{{d^3}q}}{{{{\left( {2\pi } \right)}^3}}}{e^{ - i\vec q.\vec r}}\frac{1}{{{{\vec q}^4}}}}  = ?$

Comment: Since the function is radial and homogeneous degree $-4$, the FT should also be radial and homogeneous degree $-3+4=1$. Thus it is $$C|r|$$ for some constant $C$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The constant for may analytical work is important.

Comment: What work is it? Add some context to your post as well as any attempts you have made towards the answer then I will try to find the constant.